# C - how to read data from /dev/urandom into a uint64_t variable?

Tags: c, linux

As will probably be painfully obvious, I do not normally program in C.  However, after a lot of searching it seems to be the most efficient language to implement what I want to do, namely generate a large number (10 million) of random integers quickly (using an Xorshift* algorithm). The intention is to seed it with /dev/urandom.

I have cobbled together the code below from a variety of sources.  It now compiles without warning or error with gcc 5.4.

However, when run, the program is not pulling a random seed from /dev/urandom (or at least it's not populating the value of "seed" correctly). In fact, the value of "seed" seems to always end up the same on my system - 4195584.

In summary, the variation of Xorshift* I cribbed from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift#Variations) requires a uint64_t seed, which I want to pull from /dev/urandom, which is not working currently in my program as it stands.

Environment is Linux (Ubuntu 16.04).

Assistance appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <inttypes.h>



int main (void) {

uint64_t seed;
uint64_t newval;
long int a;

int fd = open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY);
read(fd,(uint64_t*)seed,sizeof(seed));
close(fd);

printf("Seed:");
printf("%" PRIu64 "\n",seed);


for ( a = 1; a <= 10000000; a = a + 1 ) {
  seed ^= seed << 12;
  seed ^= seed >> 25;
  seed ^= seed << 27;
  seed = seed * UINT64_C(2685821657736338717);
  newval = abs(seed);
  printf("%" PRIu64 "\n",newval);
}

}
```

Comment: Whatever an "xorshift*" algorithm might be, your code ressembles to the hardware-implementation of a LFSR. You should get the software version, the code shown is worse than imperformant. Anyway, it is not clear what your problem is. If it is about reading `urandom`, the algorithm is irrelevant. See [ask], provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you need to pass the address of the object to read:

```
read( fd , &seed , sizeof(seed));
           ^^^^^
```

Comment: Looks like a canditate to close for typo.